# What is the difference between "intermediate" and "intermediary" when both mean the same thing?

Tags: adjectives, suffixes, nuance

I have a tendency to say

> 1. This case is intermediary
> 2. This case is an intermediate one
> 3. This is an intermediate case

I probably would stumble over

> 4. This is an intermediary case

and come to a halt at

> 5. This case is intermediate

Grammatically there seems to be no difference: both are adjectives (and, according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intermediary), in this context both even mean exactly the same thing).

In other words, I seem to prefer *intermediate* for modifying a noun, but *intermediary* for predicating it. Is there any rationale for this preference, or can/should I use *intermediate* and *intermediary* interchangeably¹?

<sub>¹ Only when they mean the same thing, of course.</sub>

Comment: It's almost impossible to determine why one synonym is more popular than another.  It seems to be true with your twins:  the google finds about 10 times more uses of *intermediate stage* than of *intermediary stage*.  Perhaps it's because *intermediary* also has use as a noun, meaning a person who mediates.

Comment: Well, by definition, when they both mean the same thing there is no difference.  Perhaps you're interested in the difference between them when they *don't* mean the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oxford Learner’s Dictionaries, broadly backed up by Google Books, does not agree with you: *this case is intermediate* is fine; *this case is intermediary* is not.

Merriam-Webster gives *intermediate* as a synonym for *intermediary*, but [Oxford Learner’s does not: it defines ***intermediary*** as *go between* only:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/intermediary)

> 1 a person or an organization that helps other people or organizations to make an agreement by being a means of communication between them
>
> → SYNONYM [**go-between**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/go-between), [**mediator**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/mediator)
>
> ● *Financial institutions act as intermediaries between lenders and borrowers*.
>   ● *All talks have so far been conducted through an intermediary.*
>
> →Intermediary *adjective* [only before noun]
>   ● *to play an intermediary role in the dispute*

On ***intermediate*** Merriam-Webster and Oxford agree [(Merriam-Webster):](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intermediate)

> **1** : being or occurring at the middle place, stage, or degree or between extremes
>
> **2** : of or relating to an intermediate school <*an intermediate curriculum*>

Google books shows that usage conforms to Oxford’s definition. We likely have a lot more cases that are intermediate between mild and severe than go-between cases, and as we would expect Goodle Ngrams shows [*intermediate case* 40-50 times as frequent as *intermediary case*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intermediary%20case%2Fintermediate%20case&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28intermediary%20case%20/%20intermediate%20case%29%3B%2Cc0). Raw Google gives [seven instances of *case is intermediary* only](https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22case%20is%20intermediary%22) (which violate Oxford’s only-before-noun prescription), two of which are your post’s; but it gives [150,000 instances of *case is intermediate*](https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22case%20is%20intermediate%22). You can have go-between roles, and Ngram shows [*intermediary role* six times as frequent as *intermediate role*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intermediary%20role%2Fintermediate%20role&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28intermediary%20role%20/%20intermediate%20role%29%3B%2Cc0) of late.